# Broadcast data's change from service to many controllers after ajax-load

Tags: javascript, angularjs, pointers, scope

I have angular service, that load data from server, and some controllers are dependent on this servic (they use data, that was loaded via service). But data is loaded by ajax-request (and it is async), and controllers retrieve pointer to any array, and it is replaced by another loaded array after ajax-request is finished. Service have actual pointer on array, and controllers do not have.

Here are some code with comments:

```
angular.module('someApp')
.factory('operationService', ['$http', function($http){
    // now, after app started, some controllers will receive pointer to this empty array
    var operations = [];

    $http.get('some-link').success(function(data){
        // controllers have some pointer to old array, but we replace variable
        // controllers have old array, not loaded from server
        operations = data;
    });
    return {
        // controllers will take pointer via this method
        getOperations: function () {
            return operations;
        }
    };
}])
.controller('SomeController', ['$scope', 'operationService', function($scope, opService){
    // here we receive empty array
    $scope.operations = opService.getOperations();
    // and sometimes, when ajax-request will be finished, we still have empty array :(
}]);
```

What is "best practice" to have actual data everywhere in angular app? I know, that I can modify array with "splice" and "push", but that is very "dirty" way.

Comment: Are you against callbacks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways in which to only make one http call, however I am limited to how I can do this by software versions we use here.

You could use a **promise** or set your http request to only occur once. However, the http setting only works in later versions of Angular. Check your version.

As for best practices **Use what your stack allows** there is no one way of doing anything. A best practices for async operations include (but not limited to) callbacks, promises, HTTP settings, and most importantly - what works in your current stack configuration.

The below factory code uses its own way of managing multiple callbacks for the **same** data. After the first call, any subsequent factory call will hit the callbackStack and pile up until the **HTTP** request returns with data. Then each callback will fire and get the data.

```
angular.module('someApp').factory('operationService', ['$http', function($http){

  var callbackStack = [];
  var firstCallMade = false;
  var factoryServerData;

  return {
    getOperations: getOperations
  };

  function getOperations( ctrlCallback ){
    callbackStack.push( ctrlCallback );
    if( firstCallMade ){ return; }
    firstCallMade = true;
    getOperationsHttpRequest();
  };

  function getOperationsHttpRequest(){
    $http.get('some-link').success( factoryCallback );
  }

  function factoryCallback( operations ){
    // handle !operations here if you need to.
    factoryServerData = operations || null;
    callbackStack.forEach( giveCtrlCallbackResponse );
  }

  function giveCtrlCallbackResponse( ctrlCallback ){
    ctrlCallback( factoryServerData );
  }
}]);
```

By using a callback in each controller, you will assure that you will get whatever is returned by the http call. You will still get an empty array, but only if that is what the server returned, not because of async issues with controller loading.

```
.controller('SomeController', ['$scope', 'operationService', function($scope, opService){

  opService.getOperations( getOperationsCallback );
  // Now $scope.operations will wait until your server responds.

  function getOperationsCallback( response ){
    $scope.operations = response;
  }
}]);


.controller('SomeOtherController', ['$scope', 'operationService', function($scope, opService){

  opService.getOperations( getOperationsCallback );
  // Now $scope.operations will wait until your server responds.

  function getOperationsCallback( response ){
    $scope.operations = response;
  }
}]);
```

**NOTE** if you are using nested controllers, then the first controller can make the call and then broadcast the results to all nested controllers as well. You would catch it with scope.$on....